# Adding "VMs by Software Product" to XenCenter's view menu

Tags: xenserver, xen

XenCenter has a "VMs by Operating System" dropdown menu.

I would like to have a similar menu "VMs by Software Product" which displays VMs grouped by certain software products and releases. Each of our VMs runs one major software product, and the idea is to have an overview of which software release is installed on which VM.

It seems that the OS type and version is reported back from the VM to the Xen host / to XenCenter: http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/6.1.0/1.0/en_gb/api/?c=VM_guest_metrics

I have also found the code that actually executes the XenCenter search: https://github.com/xenserver/xenadmin/blob/master/XenModel/XenSearch/Search.cs

But I have no idea how to report back my own data and display this in XenCenter. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to do this in a automatic way (when your Software product updates you want to see the update in Xencenter).

A workaround for this situation is to use **TAGS** or **vApps**.

Using TAGS you can identify the VMs by software product.

vApps are available on XenServer 6.2 and the most recent version of XenCenter, using vApps you can group VMs depending on a arbitrary parameter. For example, defining VMs for testing enviroment or production. You can perform actions on those vms, like turning them off or on.

You can find more information on the Manual Guide

http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/34969-102-704897/reference.pdf